# Does any of the Lumia or other Windows Phone has LED Notification ? (from factory, not by tweaks)

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, notifications, nokia-lumia-1020

I've recently managed to enable LED notification on Lumia 1020 which is currently running on Windows 10 Mobile. It works great but it keeps ON  until I see related notification. I want to make it blink.

That's why, I want to know this before trying making changes to registry to get it to 'blink', maybe it works or maybe not. But before that I want to be sure.

I have tried searching specifications, videos and forums to get the related details, but its not very clear to me. Because phones like from HTC used to have notification LED. And I don't know where can I get to know about registry settings.

I hope Windows Phone users can tell this better!

(This is my first question here. Thank you!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HP Elite x3 has an LED for notifications and was testing a firmware update to enable this a while back. I'm not sure though if this has ever been released to customers.
https://twitter.com/zacbowden/status/819345221695717376

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Thomas. :) I believe I can start some tweaks then. Comments on that Tweet were interesting thou...I wonder what's new that Microsoft is cooking :v Coz they seem to' have abandoned a loyal consumer-base.